# Catch outgoing packets with c++

Tags: c++

Is there some way in c++ through which I can catch all the packets being transferred on a port (by some other app) and get there data. I need to see what kind of data is sent by a specific app and process it.

Comment: This post is pretty low quality and will likely be closed. But check out Wireshark - it's open source.

Comment: Its more of a learning purpose stuff too..

Comment: @Steve is correct, wireshark is a good tool. Follow up on that, maybe learn to tinker in Lua and write a script to get the values out. But again, this is all opinion pieces. Please take the time to see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [take the tour of stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour); they are invaluable. This is a programming Q/A, not a referral service for interesting applications unless it's specifically required by your code and you need genuine API help to be able to implement it.

Comment: I need to store the outgoing data of packet for later use in a c++ application. Aint possible with wireshark.

Comment: I log power generation data that is transmitted over the internet from my solar panels using Wireshark logging utilities and process the files every week or so using C++. Separate the jobs.

Comment: Wireshark can save packets to a file which you can later process. It sure can do it.

Comment: C++ does not acknowledge the existence of ports or packets, so you're going to have to use third party tools or libraries. At the very minimum we need your target OS to begin making good suggestions. Other than Wireshark, that is. Wireshark's the right idea even if you wind up using it as an example and calling through to the same packet capture API it is using on your target platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Linux or a similar OS, you can use libpcap to capture packets. Under the hood it uses Berkeley Packet Filters for filtering packets that meet the criteria you define.

On Windows you can try npcap (newer) or winpcap -- which are the libraries WireShark uses internally to capture packets. The usage of those libraries is similar to libpcap.

Another option for getting packets sent and received by a program would be hooking the send/receive functions; on Linux that could be as easy as writing a shared library with `send` and `recv` functions, and then using `LD_PRELOAD` when running the target application to make it call your `send` and `recv` functions instead, which would do something with the packet contents, then call the original function (which can be looked up using a call to `dlsym` with `RTLD_NEXT` and the function name).

Comment: Or using ptrace(). For a example of how that works look at the strace utility. Maybe just capture the data using starce and process it from there.